# Send data to specific client from another client with a server in middle[C#]

Tags: c#, winforms, server, tcp, client

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find as they are all answering to send message to all clients. What I want to achieve is multiple clients request to server to request data from another client and other client sends data to server telling it that data is for requesting client and so. I don't know how to achieve this. I'm new to this.

What I want to achieve:

[image]

I have tried with Data sending client to listen and requesting client to connect to it and transfer data. I have achieved this on local network but to make it work online it needs port forwarding and my user will be a lot of different people so port forwarding is not possible for every user. So I can rent a server which will act as a center of transfer. I programmed a test server in console which will listen to a server IP:port X and accept new clients and their data on port X and forward it to server IP:port Y but what this does is send data to all clients on port Y. I cannot send it to clients public ip address directly for obvious reasons. I understand that all the requesting clients are connected to port Y but I cannot create and assign new ports to all the clients interacting. So I want a way to determine how to request and receive the data without the need of assigning or creating new ports to different clients on same server.

What I have tried:

**Server code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test___server
{
    class server
    {
        public static string serverIP = "192.168.0.102";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread listenSendingThread = new Thread(listenSending);
            listenSendingThread.IsBackground = true;
            listenSendingThread.Start();
            Thread listenReceivingThread = new Thread(listenReceiving);
            listenReceivingThread.IsBackground = true;
            listenReceivingThread.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static List<TcpClient> listSending = new List<TcpClient>();
        public static List<TcpClient> listReceiving = new List<TcpClient>();
        public static TcpClient clientSending = null;
        private static void listenSending()
        {
            TcpListener listenerSending = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), 5319);
            listenerSending.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server listening to " + serverIP + ":5319");
            while(true)
            {
                clientSending = listenerSending.AcceptTcpClient();
                listSending.Add(clientSending);
                Console.WriteLine("Sender connection received from " + clientSending.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
            }
        }
        private static void send()
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(clientSending.GetStream());
            sw.WriteLine(message);
            sw.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent!");
        }

        public static string message = string.Empty;
            
        private static void listenReceiving()
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), 0045);
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server listening to " + serverIP + ":0045");
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                listReceiving.Add(client);
                Console.WriteLine("Receiver connection received from " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                message = sr.ReadLine();
                send();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Requesting client code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test____admin
{
    class admin
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Begin");
            string serverIP = "192.168.0.102";
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
            clientSocket.Connect(serverIP,  );
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reading");
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Request satisfying client code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test___client
{
    class client
    {
        public static string serverIP = "192.168.0.102";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            clientConnect();
        }

        private static void clientConnect()
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, 0045);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                sw.WriteLine("Karan!");
                sw.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider websockets or SignalR ?

Comment: I have read about it but I hope to make changes in the code with current method of TCPListener and TCPClient I currently have. As the application is very big and it's nearly impossible for me to change everything. Is there any method for me to achieve what I want with what I already have?

Comment: Use Async method for listener.  The Accept method gets all new connections from clients which is a socket.  When a new client connection you can get the remote endpoint (the client IP address) and create a table of connected clients.  Then when you need to send to remote clients get the IP addresses from the table.

Comment: @jdweng can I achieve this by sending the data to clients public IP address without a need to port forward on clients side?

Comment: Not with TCP.   You need a connection with TCP which is a socket.  TCP the connection is started in client.  So server need a list of connected clients.  The only way of getting the list is by capturing the sockets in the Accept method.

Comment: Yeah I can get list of clients but to forward the data to that specific clients does the client need to port forward?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very low-level API, and doing it the right way is challenging. Instead, try [YARP](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/index.html) as a reverse proxy. The requesting client should notify the reverse proxy about the desired destination client. One option is sending the destination client name in the [request header](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/header-routing.html). You will also need to split a single server request into multiple client requests, then merge their responses into a single one. You can achieve it by implementing [Transphorms](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/transforms.html).

I'm not sure this approach applies to your situation because clients should implement server API using REST, Grpc or any other supported technology.

Comment: Sure I will consider your answer. As I'm new to this so I will need sometime to research on it. Thanks for answering.